# Regular Expression on IOS shortcuts for Line Matching

Tags: ios, regex, shortcut

I'm trying to extract activities and the corresponding date and time from the list below. I'm using the shortcut app on iOS for the regex matching.

In the end I want to have the name of the activity and the time for the given weekday (parameter). Testing on https://regex101.com/

If you need more information let me know. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

### Issue

So the issue is that with the current regex (see below) only activities are shown where the given weekday parameter is followed immediately. In the regex below it will only match

> Pilates
>
> **Mittwoch 11:00 - 12:00**
>
> **Mittwoch 17:00 - 18:00**
>
> Montag 19:00 - 20:00
>
> Dienstag 17:00 - 18:00
>
> Dienstag 18:00 - 19:00
>
> Donnerstag 11:00 - 12:00
>
> Donnerstag 17:00 - 18:00
>
> Donnerstag 20:00 - 21:00
>
> Freitag 17:00 - 18:00
>
> Samstag 11:00 - 12:00
>
> Samstag 13:00 - 14:00
>
> Sonntag 12:00 - 13:00

### Example Code

Mittwoch (Wednesday) added as example, this will be a dynamic variable in the end.

```
([-\&\sA-zÀ-ÿ]+\n((Mittwoch)\s\d+:\d+\s-\s\d+:\d+\n)+)
```

### Example data

> Pilates
>
> Montag 19:00 - 20:00
>
> Dienstag 17:00 - 18:00
>
> Dienstag 18:00 - 19:00
>
> **Mittwoch 11:00 - 12:00**
>
> **Mittwoch 17:00 - 18:00**
>
> Donnerstag 11:00 - 12:00
>
> Donnerstag 17:00 - 18:00
>
> Donnerstag 20:00 - 21:00
>
> Freitag 17:00 - 18:00
>
> Samstag 11:00 - 12:00
>
> Samstag 13:00 - 14:00
>
> Sonntag 12:00 - 13:00

### Expected Result

> Pilates
>
> Mittwoch 11:00 - 12:00
>
> Mittwoch 17:00 - 18:00

Comment: Hi, I added the ios tag in order to indicate the regex engine that is used for the shortcut app. I thought this would help suggesting a solution. But you are right I will update the description with an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/VxsKeI/3/).

The regular expression that I use it is this one. Matching only if the name of activitiy is **Pilates**.

```
(Pilates\s*)|(Mittwoch [012]\d:[0-5]\d - [012]\d:[0-5]\d\s*)
```

If the name of the activity is a set of characters then, try this one.

```
^(\w+\s\s)|(Mittwoch [012]\d:[0-5]\d - [012]\d:[0-5]\d\s*)
```

As you say, the parameter for this example is **Mittwoch**, you can change it as your needs.

Hope this help you.